# Error: can't display dash lines (broken lines) when zooming PageLayout

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I am working with PageLayoutControl, its mapframe include elements: lines, texts. And I am getting an error when zooming: If I zoom the pagelayout to 100% ( smaller than 110%), it can display "Dash Lines". But, if zoom to 120% (or larger), all "dash lines" become "solid lines". Please see attached screenshots:[image: zoom to 100%]

[image: zoom to 120%]

And another problem: when I print the pagelayout, all dash lines become solid lines.

Are there anyone know what's wrong ?

Thanks and regards,

Tai

Comment: And I thought *I* was picky! Sorry to say I don't know what might be causing that. If you can create a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the issue and [host it](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/900/gis-se-approved-hosts-for-example-datasets?cb=1) somewhere, perhaps someone will be able to help you. Otherwise that seems like a pretty minor problem to me and I would just say "deal with it" to the customer.

Comment: Thanks blah. If I use the zoom command of Map, it is ok. But, when I use the zoom command of PageLayout, it is not ok (dash lines become solid lines). Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Hi, I created and uploaded demo example. Please download at the link: http://www.mediafire.com/?7p9nbluha1gi33j   . Thank you for your help

Comment: Got it to compile at 10.1 SP1 after some fiddling and I can confirm I'm seeing the same thing. The dotted and dashed lines become solid lines once you zoom in past a certain point in layout mode.

Comment: Here is the 10.x version if anyone's interested: http://wfurl.com/05c4b47

Comment: Your mean is Arcgis 10.1 Service Pack 1 ? Are there any other way ?

Comment: I'm saying I reproduced the issue you had at 10.1 SP1. Meaning it's still a problem at the version that was just released 2 days ago :(

Comment: Thanks Blah238. Do you know how to fix this error ?

Comment: No, I do not. I shared the 10.x version in hopes of making it more likely that someone who might know how to fix it tries it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is a [known issue](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/14810) and has to do with how Simple Line Symbols are drawn using [GDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface). If the line width exceeds 1 point when displayed, it is drawn as a solid line. The workaround is to use a [Cartographic Line Symbol](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000029w000000) instead.

Comment: Thanks blah238, Could you give me an example how to create a dot line and dash line with Cartographic Line Symbol ?

Comment: There is a dashed line example in my 3rd link: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000029w000000

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand about values: pttrn, for example: pttrn[1] = 7 (why is it 7 ?? not 9, or 10). How can I change it to create a dash line like this: - - - - - - - or dot line: . . . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

By replacing the interface `ISimpleLineSymbol` by the interface `ILineSymbol`, the program works without problems of zoom, the main obstacle for using `ILineSymbol` object that it has'nt style attribut, i searched about setting style for `ILineSymbol` but without a result.

in my case i use this code to get the symbol from a symbology control.

```
ILineSymbol line_symbol = (ILineSymbol)symbolForm.GetItem(esriSymbologyStyleClass.esriStyleClassLineSymbols, (((lyr as IFeatureLayer) as IGeoFeatureLayer).Renderer as ISimpleRenderer).Symbol  )  ;
```

you can find the GetItem in [this sample C# script](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/ViewCodePages/8106010D-5C38-4790-8A9C-7D7E42881629SymbolForm.cs.htm)

i tested the program using a serialized ILineSymbol object in an XML file , you will find the test version in [this link](http://ge.tt/9DdfdvQ/v/0).

Comment: Thanks geogeek, but I don't know how to use your way to create a dash line: - - - - - - - - - or dot line: ............. I am not clear about xml file, it doesn't contain dash style or dot style ?